# why Instant date in java shows time 4:56:02Z for a given date which is before 1884

Tags: java

For my work, I wanted to get an Instant date for a given date as per given ZoneID, Everything was wroking fine, but when I checked with old date (year 1883 or before). The time appears as 04:56, instead of 5:00.

For any date after 18 nov 1883, it gives me correct result like 1883-11-19T05:00:00Z

Can someone helps, why time appear as 4:56 for older dates ?

```
public static String firstdate = "18831118";

LocalDate localFirstDate = LocalDate.parse(firstdate, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd"));
LocalDateTime localDateTime = localFirstDate.atStartOfDay();
Instant instantFirstDate = localDateTime.toInstant(ZoneId.of("America/New_York").getRules().getOffset(localDateTime));
```

Output

```
1883-11-18T04:56:02Z
```

```
public static String firstdate = "18831119";

LocalDate localFirstDate = LocalDate.parse(firstdate, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd"));
LocalDateTime localDateTime = localFirstDate.atStartOfDay();
Instant instantFirstDate = localDateTime.toInstant(ZoneId.of("America/New_York").getRules().getOffset(localDateTime));
```

Output

```
1883-11-19T05:00:00Z
```

In the later case, it shows time perfectly `5:00:00Z`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming `localDateTime` is declared as `LocalDateTime localDateTime = localFirstDate.atStartOfDay();`)

If you look at what's returned by `ZoneId.of("America/New_York").getRules().getOffset(localDateTime)`, you'll see that it is an offset of about -4:56. The instants are calculated using this offset, so they have the time of 04:56.

Why does New York has such a weird time zone offset in 1883 before November 17? Apparently, on November 18, [Standard time zones forms by railroads in US & Canada](https://www.onthisday.com/date/1883/november/18). It is easy to imagine that there is no standard on-the-hour time zones before that date.

If you look at other time zones, such as `Asia/Macau`, you'll see that most of them have weird offsets more than a hundred years ago. Messing up time zones is a natural thing that we humans do :).

In your specific case, if you would like to use the standardised time zone offset before 18 November 1883, you could just apply the `ZoneOffsetTransitionRule` you get from `ZoneId.of("America/New_York").getRules().getTransitionRules()` manually, but I am not sure how much sense that would make.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your inputs. I will try to handle offset issue somehow.